# CakePHP 3: Setting options for 'contain' when paginating

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.1, cakephp-3.x

What's the correct way to **limit the number of contained associated records when paginating**?

[The docs don't appear to address](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html) how to set options for 'contain' while paginating, but `$paginate['contain']['AssociatedModel']['limit'] = 1;` seemed to make sense. However, that line is resulting the following error for me in CakePHP 3.1.3:

```
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in ...\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\EagerLoader.php on line 312
```

The error being generated because, in the line `$pointer[$table] = $options + $pointer[$table];`, `$options` is `1` and `$pointer[$table]` is an array.

Confusingly, setting `$paginate['contain']['AssociatedModel']['fields']` works as expected, but setting `'limit'` or `'order'` results in that same error.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that setting `$paginate['contain']['AssociatedModel']['fields'] = [...]` works, other options need to be set using functions. The following code fixes my problem:

```
$paginate['contain']['AssociatedModel'] = function($q) {
    return $q
        ->select([...])
        ->limit(1)
        ->order([...]);
};
```